# How to return value from VLOOKUP into a cell?

Tags: vba

I have the following piece of code for Vlookup. The function works fine but the found out value aint getting displayed in the cell. However if i had a used Msgbox function the found out value is shown. The question is doesnt VLOOKUP result be captured in a cell?

```
Sub Example_of_Vlookup()
Dim lookFor As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Integer
Dim found As String
Dim lastrowrange As Long
Dim area As Range
lastrowrange = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row
Set lookFor = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("b2")
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("t:u")
Set taxRange = Range("f2", Cells(lastrowrange, 22))
col = 2

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To lastrowrange
found = Application.VLookup("B2", "T1:U4", 2, True)
If IsError(found) Then
MsgBox lookFor & " not found"
Else

area.Cells(i, 2).Value = found
End If
Next i
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Birds View: If you are not planning to use `lookFor`,`rng`, `taxRange`  then why are you declaring it? Shouldn't you be using those in the `Application.VLookup` Also I am unable to understand your code... What are you trying to search and where? If you can add a snapshot or a small description then that would help...

Comment: HI Sid, I initially used those variables. Yet for a test piece I used the actual cell refernces. Idea is simple - I have country names in Column B.Inention is to pull out the Area under which country belongs - My look up values are in column S(country) and T(area) and display the result in column F

Answer (score 1):

You did not set the range "area" equal to anything, so this line won't show your answer properly:

```
area.Cells(i, 2).Value = found
```

Change `area.Cells(i,2).value` to `sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i,2).value` or wherever you want your answer to show. Or, set area equal to something if you want to use `area.cells`.

Answer (score 1):

> Idea is simple - I have country names in Column B.Inention is to pull out the Area under which country belongs - My look up values are in column S(country) and T(area) and display the result in column F – Sayanth Sasidharan 25 mins ago

If my understanding is correct as per your explanation then you do not need to use a loop. Let Excel do the Dirty Work ;) You will end up with far less code.

Let's say your sheet looks like this

[image]

**Logic**:

1. Find the last row of Col B
2. Insert the `Vlookup` formula in `F1:F & LastRow` in one go
3. Convert them to values.

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example_of_Vlookup()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,S:T,2,0)),"",VLOOKUP(B1,S:T,2,0))
        .Range("F1:F" & lRow).Formula = _
        "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],C[13]:C[14],2,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-4],C[13]:C[14],2,0))"

        .Range("F1:F" & lRow).Value = .Range("F1:F" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Sid! That was precise! Huge heaps of appreciation to you!

Comment: Hi Sid! One more quick one! I need sub area also which is mapped under column U. I need to bring it in Column G. I used something like this -                                                  .Range("G1:G" & lRow).Formula = _
        "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-5],C[14]:C[15],2,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-5],C[14]:C[15],2,0))"      

                     .Range("G1:G" & lRow).Value = .Range("G1:G" & lRow).Value. Couldnt get the result in Column G. Could you tell me where I went wrong?